# How can I define a project variable with candle in WIX?

Tags: msbuild, wix, installation, wix3.5

I want to take an existing project variable and extend it but I want it to be global so that I don't have to include it in each wxs file.

The one I want to extend is:

```
$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)
```

I want to turn to make

```
var.MyProject.TargetDir.Help=$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)Help\
```

How can I do this globablly?

I know I can do this:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <?define var.MyProject.TargetDir.Help=$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)Help\ ?>
```

but then I have to do that in each file or I have to create a wxi file and include that in each file.  I want this to be predefined before the build.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define preprocessor variables with Candle as so:

```
candle.exe -dMyVariable=whatever.
```

This is not a hard answer to find with google but my problem was that I was trying to do:

```
candle.exe -dMyProject.TargetDir.Help=$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)Help\
```

So I was a little bit careless here forgetting that `$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)` is also created by candle and I can't just reference that before it's created.

You would have to manually find the path of the file as so:

```
candle.exe -dMyProject.TargetDir.Help=$(SolutionDir)MyProject\bin\$(Configuration)\Help\
```

Also just a quick note, your variable that you create does not get prefixed with `var.'